# Why are the respondents never shown?

Tags: film-techniques, oasis-supersonic

In the docufilm *Oasis: Supersonic* I noticed that the respondents are never shown in frame while they talk, some videos are shown instead.

Is there any reason? Is this a common technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partly because [the brothers refused to be in the same room together](http://www.montereyhowick.co.nz/movies/12113.php):

> On the making of the film, director Mat Whitecross explains "After conversations with Noel and Liam, we agreed the film should be constructed solely from archive footage with contemporary voices telling the story. The voice-over approach helped keep things feeling in the moment. **We knew it was unlikely Noel and Liam would want to do their interviews together, but with voice-over, the viewer would feel they were having a conversation**."